# ApolloBoost was initialized with unsupported options:

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, vue-apollo

I'm trying to **disable cache** on Apollo, therefore I'm following the documentation [apollo-client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html)
, but I cannot success, I get all the time this *warning* `ApolloBoost was initialized with unsupported options: defaultOptions`

Does anyone have the same *warning* ?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'

    const defaultOptions = {
      watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        errorPolicy: 'ignore'
      },
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        errorPolicy: 'all'
      }
    }

    const client = new ApolloClient({

    defaultOptions: defaultOptions,
    )};
```

Comment: Did you import the ApolloClient from 'apollo-client' or 'apollo-boost'?

Comment: @Intellidroid apollo-boost, already updated the code

Comment: If you need to add more configuration options I believe you need to import the libraries separately so ApolloClient from 'apollo-client' not 'apollo-boost'

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/boost-migration.html

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it's because you are using [Apollo Boost](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/tree/master/packages/apollo-boost), a wrapper around Apollo Client with slightly different API.

Try changing your import from:

`import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";`

to:

`import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";`

or in v3:

`import { ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';`

---

The "apollo-client" is more low level and harder to use. That's probably why the team created "apollo-boost".

But looking at the source code "apollo-boost" is a good way to understand how to use the low-level "apollo-client". For example:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { FetchResult } from 'apollo-link';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

// in v3, the types moved:
// import { ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: '/graphql',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
  },
});
```

See also the docs on [migration](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/boost-migration/) from Apollo Boost to Apollo Client like Intellidroid said.